# Why doesn't the following piece of code input data properly?

Tags: java, android, android-layout

```
package com.example.my.galgu;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView textView;
    long first=1, second=1, answer;
    boolean a=false ,s=false ,m=false ,d=false;
    int i=0;
    String wholesome, goti;
    Button ba, bs, bm, bd, be;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        ba = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ba);
        bs = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bs);
        bm = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bm);
        bd = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bd);
        be = (Button) findViewById(R.id.be);

        be.setEnabled(false);
    }

    public void disable(){
    ba.setEnabled(false);
    bs.setEnabled(false);
    bm.setEnabled(false);
    bd.setEnabled(false);
    }
```

A method for each of the buttons from one to zero. 
The problem lies somewhere in the below method where the first and second
are stored. The method first checks if any of the +,-,*,/ buttons are 
pressed and then stores the value in either the first or second variable.
The last digit for the first variable is omitted. And I can't say why.

```
    public void onone(View view){
    if(a||s||m||d){
        second *= i;
        i = i * 10;
        second += 1;
    }else{
       first = Integer.parseInt(textView.getText().toString());
    }
    wholesome = textView.getText().toString();
    if(wholesome.equals("0"))
    textView.setText("1");
    else{
        textView.setText(wholesome + "1");
    }
}

    public void ontwo(View view){
        if(a||s||m||d){
            second *= i;
            i = i * 10;
            second += 2;
        }else{
            first = Integer.parseInt(textView.getText().toString());
        }
        wholesome = textView.getText().toString();
        if(wholesome.equals("0"))
            textView.setText("2");
        else{
            textView.setText(wholesome + "2");
        }
    }

    public void onthree(View view){
        if(a||s||m||d){
            second *= i;
            i = i * 10;
            second += 3;
        }else{
            first = Integer.parseInt(textView.getText().toString());
        }
        wholesome = textView.getText().toString();
        if(wholesome.equals("0"))
            textView.setText("3");
        else{
            textView.setText(wholesome + "3");
        }
    }

    public void onfour(View view){
        if(a||s||m||d){
            second *= i;
            i = i * 10;
            second += 4;
        }else{
            first = Integer.parseInt(textView.getText().toString());
        }
        wholesome = textView.getText().toString();
        if(wholesome.equals("0"))
            textView.setText("4");
        else{
            textView.setText(wholesome + "4");
        }
    }

    public void onfive(View view){
        if(a||s||m||d){
            second *= i;
            i = i * 10;
            second += 5;
        }else{
            first = Integer.parseInt(textView.getText().toString());
        }
        wholesome = textView.getText().toString();
        if(wholesome.equals("0"))
            textView.setText("5");
        else{
            textView.setText(wholesome + "5");
        }
    }

    public void onsix(View view){
        if(a||s||m||d){
            second *= i;
            i = i * 10;
            second += 6;
        }else{
            first = Integer.parseInt(textView.getText().toString());
        }
        wholesome = textView.getText().toString();
        if(wholesome.equals("0"))
            textView.setText("6");
        else{
            textView.setText(wholesome + "6");
        }
    }

    public void onseven(View view){
        if(a||s||m||d){
            second *= i;
            i = i * 10;
            second += 7;
        }else{
            first = Integer.parseInt(textView.getText().toString());
        }
        wholesome = textView.getText().toString();
        if(wholesome.equals("0"))
            textView.setText("7");
        else{
            textView.setText(wholesome + "7");
        }
    }

    public void oneight(View view){
        if(a||s||m||d){
            second *= i;
            i = i * 10;
            second += 8;
        }else{
            first = Integer.parseInt(textView.getText().toString());
        }
        wholesome = textView.getText().toString();
        if(wholesome.equals("0"))
            textView.setText("8");
        else{
            textView.setText(wholesome + "8");
        }
    }

    public void onnine(View view){
        if(a||s||m||d){
            second *= i;
            i = i * 10;
            second += 9;
        }else{
            first = Integer.parseInt(textView.getText().toString());

        }
        wholesome = textView.getText().toString();
        if(wholesome.equals("0"))
            textView.setText("9");
        else{
            textView.setText(wholesome + "9");
        }
    }

    public void onzero(View view){
        if(a||s||m||d){
            second *= i;
            i = i * 10;
            second += 1;
        }else{
            first = Integer.parseInt(textView.getText().toString());
        }
        wholesome = textView.getText().toString();
        if(wholesome.equals("0"))
            textView.setText("0");
        else{
            textView.setText(wholesome + "0");
        }
    }

    public void ona(View view){
        a = true;
        wholesome = textView.getText().toString();
        textView.setText(wholesome + "+");
        disable();
        be.setEnabled(true);
    }

    public void ons(View view){
        s = true;
        wholesome = textView.getText().toString();
        textView.setText(wholesome + "-");
        disable();
        be.setEnabled(true);
    }

    public void onm(View view){
        m = true;
        wholesome = textView.getText().toString();
        textView.setText(wholesome + "*");
        disable();
        be.setEnabled(true);
    }

    public void ond(View view){
        d = true;
        wholesome = textView.getText().toString();
        textView.setText(wholesome + "/");
        disable();
        be.setEnabled(true);
    }

    public void one(View view){
       if(a){
            answer = first + second;
        }
        else if (s){
            answer = first - second;
        }
        else if (m){
            answer = first * second;
        }
        else if (d){
            answer = first / second;
        }

        goti = String.valueOf(answer);
        textView.setText(goti);
        second = 1;
        i = 0;
        a = false;
        s = false;
        m = false;
        d = false;
        ba.setEnabled(true);
        bs.setEnabled(true);
        bm.setEnabled(true);
        bd.setEnabled(true);
    }

    public void once(View view){
        textView.setText("0");
        second = 1;
        i = 0;
        ba.setEnabled(true);
        bs.setEnabled(true);
        bm.setEnabled(true);
        bd.setEnabled(true);
        be.setEnabled(false);
        a = false;
        s = false;
        m = false;
        d = false;
    }

}
```

Comment: Please isolate the problem in as few lines of code as possible.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Unfortunately you've posted a *lot* of code, with only a fairly vague description of what you're seeing, and no indication of what diagnostics you've performed. What exactly do you mean by "The last digit for the first variable is omitted"? Have you tried debugging, and putting breakpoints at appropriate points?